# Need to get a count of each differnt value in a column, via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of names and I need a count of how many times the name appears within the column. I am trying to use LINQ but I don't fully understand the syntax of what is happening below.

```
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("C:\WORK\TestFile.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    Dim AddCol As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("b2")
    Dim lastRow As Integer = AddCol.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Dim Lastof As String = ("b2:" & "b" & lastRow & """").Replace("""", "")
    Dim excelColumn As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range(Lastof)
    'MsgBox(Lastof)

    Dim Lister As New List(Of String)()

    For Each Names In excelColumn
        Lister.Add(Names.value)

    Next

    Dim Result As New List(Of String)
    Result = Lister.Distinct().ToList


    For Each uniqueItem In Result

        Dim myList As New List(Of String) From {uniqueItem}
        Dim groupedNames = myList.GroupBy(Function(x) x)
        If groupedNames IsNot Nothing AndAlso groupedNames.Count > 0 Then
            Dim msg As String = Nothing
            For Each person In groupedNames
                msg += person.Key & "-" & person.Count.ToString & vbCrLf
            Next
            MsgBox(msg)
        End If


    Next
```

Comment: This is awfully close to your previous question...You need to scrap your "For Each uniqueItem" iteration and just go straight into the GroupedNames logic using "Lister.GroupBy"

Comment: @soohoonigan Thank you! That worked great! I couldn't comment on your answer regarding the other post I made. I will make sure to delete that post.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to delete it, I'm just saying if you need clarification on an answer you can always ask for that in the comments beneath it rather than posting a new question. Glad you got it working though

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me. I removed the "For Each uniqueItem" from my code above and it worked perfectly.

```
Dim groupedNames = Lister.GroupBy(Function(x) x)
        If groupedNames IsNot Nothing AndAlso groupedNames.Count > 0 Then
            Dim msg As String = Nothing
            For Each person In groupedNames
                msg += person.Key & "-" & person.Count.ToString & vbCrLf
            Next
            MsgBox(msg)
        End If
```